# read value of html element stored in variable with jquery

Tags: jquery

In this case:

```
$.get($(this).attr('href'), function(destino){
    //
}
```

How I can read the elements  and  which was get from file **$(this).attr('href')** and save them in a variable to use later?

I try this options, and none work:

1)

```
$titulo = $(destino).get('title');
$mensagem = $(destino).get('body');
```

2)

```
$titulo = destino.getElementByName('title');
$mensagem = destino.getElementByName('body');
```

3)

```
$titulo = destino.title;
$mensagem = destino.body;
```

4)

```
$titulo = $(destino).attr('title');
$mensagem = $(destino).attr('body');
```

I try this way and appending .text() and .val() on the end of the sentence. Someone can say how this can be made?

**UPDATE**

Following the suggestion posted on this topic, I write this code:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function(e){
        if($(this).attr('href') != 'logout.html') {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.get($(this).attr('href'), function(destino){
                var $destino = $(destino);
                $titulo = $destino.find('title').text();
                $mensagem = $destino.find('body').html();
                alert('titulo = '+$titulo+' // mensagem = '+$mensagem)
                BootstrapDialog.show({
                    title: $titulo,
                    message: $mensagem,
                    draggable: true
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

but doesn't working. When I try look at the content form $titulo and $mensagem, seems like both are empty and undefined, respectively.

**ANOTHER UPDATE**

I made another change. Now I have this code:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function(e){
        if($(this).attr('href') != 'logout.html') {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.get($(this).attr('href'), function(destino){
                var $destino = $(destino);
                $titulo = $destino.filter('title').text();
                $mensagem = $destino.filter('body').html();
                alert('titulo = '+$titulo+' // mensagem = '+$mensagem)
                BootstrapDialog.show({
                    title: $titulo,
                    message: $mensagem,
                    draggable: true
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

the value of $titulo is now correct, but the value for $mensagem not.

Comment: It depends on what destino returns.

Comment: @LShetty: You can guess from "title" and "body" it is returning a standard HTML page :)

Comment: Right, the can we also guess the DOM struct? :P and I don't do guess work :)

Comment: @LShetty: No need to guess... he only wants the title and body tags... Nothing else is specified :P( I find a lot of SO questions require guesswork :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, Right, an XML struct can also have body and title tags :)

Comment: @LShetty: And a plain text file can have them too, but when you hear hooves you don't think "zebras!" :)

Comment: Sure, and you go with the guess games and I'd stick to facts ;)

Comment: the function is handling this kind of link in my page: **<li><a href="usuario_perfil.html">Perfil</a></li>** (all links follow the same style, with diferent html files) each.

Comment: @KleberMota, instead of find('title') try filter('title') and same for filter('body')

Comment: ok, this works for $title but dont't work for $mensagem. I try the second one with filter('body').html(), filter('body').text() and filter('body').val() and just filter('body').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $('a').click(function(e){
        if($(this).attr('href') != 'logout.html') {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.get($(this).attr('href'), function(data){
                var $temp  = $('<div/>', {html:data});
                var $title = $temp.find('title').text();
                var $body  = $temp.remove('head').html();
                console.log( $title +' // '+ $body );
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

basically destino is nothing but a string to begin with. You use JQuery to convert it to a DOM structure with `$(destino)` so that step cannot be avoided.

For starters you only want to wrap destino once, as `$(destino)` has to convert the entire download into a DOM structure.

e.g.

`var $destino = $(destino)` so you only perform the costly operation once.

Then `var $title = $destino.find('title')` and `var $body = $destino.find('body')` will reference the elements you want.

if you want the text of the title it would be `$destino.find('title').text()`. If you want the HTML of the body use `$destino.find('body').html()`

*If you want something else you need to be clear about what you intended, as you have supplied 4 ways of not getting data, but no clue to what data you actually want :)*

Comment: ok, I update the question with some code I write following your suggestions. The code doesn't work, seems like $title and $message are empty after I try capture their values.

Answer (score 0):

In the handler, you are doing a $.get on all of the links in the document. I assume you just want the link that was clicked, which you can get with **$(this)**.

Try this

```
<script>
    // The ready event handler is called after the page is ready.
    $().ready(function () {
        $('a').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $.get($(this).attr('href'), function(destino) {
                alert('destino = '+destino);
             $titulo = $destino.find('title').text();
             $mensagem = $destino.find('body').html();
                alert('titulo = '+$titulo+' // mensagem = '+$mensagem)
            });

            BootstrapDialog.show({
                title: 'Draggable Dialog',
                message: $mensagem,
                draggable: true
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```